# How To Create Policy in Controller Not in IdentityHostingStartup

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity, roles, policy

I Want to Create Policy in My Controllers Not in the "IdentityHostingStartup" . Is There Any Way to Create Policy in Actions? Just Want to Create Some Policy in My Admin Panel

Easily in Startup:

```
   services.AddAuthorization(x =>
            {
                x.AddPolicy("PolicyAdmin", p => p.RequireRole("Admins"));
                x.AddPolicy("PolicyCustomers", p => p.RequireRole("Customers"));
            });
```

Any Suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to configure policies and somehow inject them in the program.

Actually, something like this exists and it's open source. The creators of IdentityServer came up with [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/).

The commercial version has an admin panel and allows advanced configuration. While the free open source version is limited. But it basically does what you want: inject policies on each request.

The code does two things: surpress error messages on non-existing policies (as these may be injected after the program is started), and inject the policies as *permission with value* through middleware.

Please take a look at the source code. This may be a good starting point. The OSS version reads the information from a json file, but you can easily replace that with another source, e.g. a database.

Comment: Thanks, But it's the only way?

Comment: If you want to use the policies, then you'll have to inject them early in the pipeline. That's what the middleware does. Authorization should take place before controllers are called, except when imperative authorization is used, that can take place in the contoller. Or wasn't that what you meant?

Comment: not really, i know how to use policies before controller, I just want to know,how to Create Policy in Controller like the way we create Policy in the IdentityHostingStartup